# How to convert a large csv file to a pickle file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pickle

I have a very big csv file (73.1 GB). I want to convert this CSV file to a Pickle file format.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have enough RAM (about 73.1 GB, maybe more, because of data structure overhead) available for all your data? If not, how do you intend to read and use the Pickle file later? Is your RAM + swap together large enough?

Comment: even if you succeed in doing that, I don't think it is the right approach for whatever you need.  To start with, while for a CSV you can read just as many rows as needed, so you can easily batch any processing, a Pickle file must be read at once as a single object. A CSV file this big when read as a Pandas dataframe can easily be many times larger, due to small objects in text being expanded to larger objects in memory.  Probably you will be better off using dask -  https://www.dask.org/

Comment: Also, if you are not doing pandas/dask, the most straightforward apporahc may be to create a database of your data - even the built-in sqlite will make this amount of data usable.

Comment: If you are going to be accessing it frequently, it may be worth making a more efficient version of the file. What do the first few lines look like?

Answer (score 1):

This takes the csv and dumpsit into a .pkl file

```py
import csv
import pickle

with open('hello.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    pickle.dump(list(reader), open('hello.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Comment: yes, but this won't work unless one has ~80GB of RAM in this case.